# Wifi connection problem and laptop freezes in 16.04 LTS in acer Aspire E 5 571

Tags: 16.04, acer

I am new to ubuntu .I installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my acer Aspire E 5 571 . It was running smoothly in offline.
Recently I am facing a problem related to wifi connection , suddenly the wifi gets disconnected and until i manually try to reconnect or reboot computer , it continues. And when this happens , my laptop's mouse pointer gets totally freezed. Sometimes keyboard works , sometimes i have to press the power button.

My question is that is it a hardware problem of my laptop or it is due to bug in ubuntu 16.04 os ?
How can I fix this wifi bugs and this freezing?

Comment: I had a similar wifi bug and got rid of it by setting the 'Method' in the 'IPv6 Settings' to 'ignore'